# Stop autocorrecting certain words

Tags: iphone, ios, autocorrect

I don’t want autocorrect to correct certain “words”

For example, I want to type “ig” without it changing to “if”

I thought I’d be able to do this by adding an “ig” to “ig” shortcut in the text replacement part of my keyboard settings.

But it still autocorrects it every now and then.

How can I completely stop autocorrect on certain words?

Comment: @SteveChambers That is for macOS. This question is tagged with iOS and iPhone.

Comment: sorry, my bad, retracted